# How can I make this email confirmation work?

Tags: php, email, sendmail, registration, confirmation

I've tried sending simple email using the mail function and it works. But when I try to insert that to my program it won't. Can someone tell me which part is wrong because I am pretty sure that it is not about xampp/sendmail config - I already tried 2 simple mailing programs and they all work except this one.

I tried my best to put(...) in place of unnecessary lines. I think the problem is that, it can't go to the part where the prog reads the email function part?

Here's my register.php:

```
<?
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['register']))
{
    include('/class.register.php');

    $register = new Register();
if($register->process()) {
    header('location: login.php');
}
else  {
    $register->show_errors();
}
}


?>

<form method= "POST" action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
<table>
<tr><td>Username:</td><td><input type="text" name="ruser" required="required" /></td></tr>
<tr><td>Email:</td><td><input type="text" name="remail" required="required" /></td></tr>
<tr><td>Password:</td><td><input type="password" name="rpass" required="required" /></td></tr>
<tr><td>Title:</td><td><input type="text" name="rtitle" required="required" /></td></tr>
<tr><td>First Name:</td><td><input type="text" name="rfname" required="required" /></td></tr>
<tr><td>Last Name:</td><td><input type="text" name="rlname" required="required" /></td></tr>
<tr><td>Mobile Number:</td><td><input type="text" name="rmobile" required="required" /></td></tr>


</table>

<input type="submit" name="register" value="Sign Up" />

</form>
```

Here's my class.register.php:

```
<?

class Register
{

...

private $errors;  

public function __construct()
{
    $this->errors = array();

    ...;

    $this->token = $_POST['token'];
    $this->passmd5 = md5($this->password);

}

public function process()
  {
  if($this->valid_data() && $this->send_email())
$this->register();

return count($this->errors)? 0: 1;

}

public function filter($var)
{
    return preg_replace('/[^a-zA-z0-9@.]/','',$var);
}
public function user_exists()
{
    ...
} 

public function email_exists()
 ...

public function register()
{
    ...

}

public function show_errors()
 echo "<h3>Errors</h3>";

    foreach($this->errors as $key=>$value)
    echo $value."<br>";

public function valid_data()
...


public function send_email()
{

$from = 'jeremiah@citydelivery.ph';
$to = $_POST['remail'];
$subject = 'Registration confirmation';
$message = 'Please click the following link or copy and paste it
into your browser to complete the registration process: ';
$message .= 'http://example.com/confirm.php?u=';
$message .= urlencode($_POST['ruser']);
$message .= '&amp;t=';
$message .= urlencode($_POST['token']);

return mail($to, $subject, $message, $from);

}


}
?>
```

Comment: Have you checked your mail logs to see if there is any helpful information there?

Comment: I kinda do not know where to check that. hehe

Comment: I don't use Xampp but it should be in \xampp\php\logs - look for something like mail.log or php_mail.log and check those files for error messages

Comment: I did check the under log the mail.php. those are like codes or something. I didnt get. hehe

Answer (score 0):

`$this->send_email` must be `$this->send_email()`

It is a function not a variable ;)

Also you use it in a statement, but `send_mail()` doesn't return anything, so it returns null, which ends up as false.

So do `return mail($to, $subject, $message, $from);` to fix that

An if statement is execute in the order until it hits a false, **when only using && (and)**

You have

```
if($this->valid_token() && $this->valid_data() && $this->send_email())
```

So it is possible it never hits `send_mail()` because `valid_data()` is for example false.

To check this use `var_dump($this->valid_token(), $this->valid_data(), $this->send_email()` The first one that hits false is your problem to fix, and so one.

Use the following process function, it checks which on is the problem. I recommend after it works to remove the `die()` functions

```
public function process()
  {
if($this->valid_token()) { die('token is the problem'); }
if($this->valid_data()) { die('valid data is the problem'); }
if($this->send_email()) { die('send email is the problem'); }

 if($this->valid_token() && $this->valid_data() && $this->send_email)
    $this->register();

return count($this->errors)? 0: 1;

}
```

Comment: oh thanks for that. Still no email confirmation was sent tho :(

Comment: Check your filter function. Also look (die($to)) if the email it is supposed to send to is also valid

Comment: I did put return right after mail. still no luck. Do you think my process function() is correct. Im kinda doubtful having two && there. Thanks for the patience man.

Comment: I do have a valid_email function, it does check if email is valid

Comment: I tried. I think having if($this->valid_token() && $this->valid_data() && $this->send_email()) does not register my inputs to my database. removing it would register em. But I will try again with the return mail($$$) :) thank you

Comment: no luck with the var_dump brother. Changing the if() in process to var_dump makes it an error.

Comment: var_dump is a method to check what the values are of an variable, using it likes an if is not the way. Also I suggest using after a var_dump the die method. That way the system stops ;)

Comment: I tried. Still.. 0. :( Ive been at this the whole day and I move from one assumption to another. Now, if I put those 3 && together. It doesnt register to the database + emails. I really hope I can understand what youre trying to tell me. Thanks for the help tho :(

Comment: says. token is the problem?

Comment: Then the problem lays in the `valid_token()` function, you have it removed so can't  say what the problem is with that

Comment: so I did remove them. What happened was I have only valid_data && send_email. Result is same, not registered in the database and no email confirmation

Comment: Tho not solve, I thank you Hendriq for being patient with me. I hope you can help me through this all the way :(

Comment: If you could update the Register class with all the functions so no ... any more, also other people can help, and me too. Now we miss some code probaly

Comment: I did update the codes up there. I hope it gets clearer now. The only problem is that when I have the send_mail function, the database always does not get updated and again, no email still. :(

Answer (score -2):

I would like to thank all of you guys who contributed. I fixed the problem by creating another file which is sendmail.php and then have it included in my register.php.

Comment: There are not enough downvotes on this to flag it as LQ, but I think it should be deleted, as it does not contain any substantive detail. I will DV and would ask that someone remove it if that proves possible in the future.